# How to escape/encode Strings to JavaScript Identifier

Tags: javascript, string, variables, identifier

I'm trying to create objects from a key/value list. My Problem is, that Object Properties have to be valid JavaScript identifiers. At least with Adobe ExtendScript I can perfectly create an Object with a wrong Property (See Example: wrong-key -> "-"-Literal is invalid).

```
var kvp = ["key;value", "wrong-key;value"];
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0 ; i < kvp.length; i++) {
    pair = kvp[i].split(";");
    obj[pair[0]] = pair[1]; 
}
alert (obj.key);
alert (obj.wrong-key); // -> Throws an Error
```

Of course I could run a `replace(/-/,"_")`, but is there any encoding/escaping function out there to accomplish this goal more generally?

thanks,
gregor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access those properties with special chars using the array notation

```
console.log(obj["wrong-key"]);
```

Comment: Ok. But just for the record, is `"wrong-key"` a valid js identifier?

Comment: What do you mean by "valid" js identifier?? Sure, you can perfectly have a property name like you have "wrong-key", although I'd avoid that if possible due to the issues you encountered.

Comment: @Juri valid in terms of the Specification. You're workaraound will do, but as you can imagina if no control about the input-data.

Comment: @grefel: If you have no control over the input data, then you cannot know the key. In that case you cannot even write in your code but you have to retrieve it dynamically. And then, the only way to access the property is bracket notation. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: This is not a workaround, this is an alternative way of accessing JavaScript object's properties. What kind of use case do you have? Where does this key-value list come from??

Comment: @Felix Yes, the `[]` is fine. The Question/Idea was, if there is any esacpe()/encode() function out there, which encodes a string to an js identifier.

Comment: @Juri The idea is to write a dynamic fucntion to create objects. it works fine with brackets. thanks!

Comment: @grefel: You can always write your own function, filtering the invalid characters if you really wanted to: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_7.6